# Trying to Export a Multi-Tabbed Report in PDF through PowerBI Online

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, export-to-pdf

I have a PowerBI Online dashboard with 24 tabs that all need to be exported to PDF as a single document. I would like to be able to download a full workbook of the 24 charts without having to export them manually one by one. Is this possible in PowerBI Online? Is there a way to build a process in PowerAutomate if not? Thanks for the help!

[PowerBI Chart Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3unB.png)

Right now when I click the "Export to DPF" button it is only allowing me to export the chart that is visible (see image - only allows the visible Chart 4 to be exported but not the others).I would like it to export all charts 1-4 in one PDF workbook.

Comment: Power BI is an interactive reports tool. This kind of dynamic UI, tables with more rows that you can fit on the screen, etc. are not suitable for export to PDF. Either change your layout and make each tab a separate report page, or go for a more suitable tool/export method.

Answer (score 0):

are you using a power bi report server or uploading to a power bi portal because when you click on file-> export-> export pdf on a power bi desktop, your reports return to pdf without any problems. I even tried this for you.